# Check if Shared Dropbox Datastore is deleted

Tags: ios, dropbox-api, datastore

In my app, I let users share datastore to share data. I want the owner of the datastore to be able to delete them though. Once a datastore is deleted by the owner, I don't want the people they shared it with to be able to access it. I thought that after I used the DBDatastoreManager to delete the datastore, that it would return nil when I tried to open it again, thus giving me a chance to just remove it from the datastore the users could open. Unfortunately, this is not the case, and it seems to maintain the local copy instead of returning nil.

Is there any way that I can check if a datastore is deleted? Obviously when I delete it on the owner's side, I can make it so they can't access it, as I have done.

Any help would be appreciated, as I can't seem to find anything on their website.

Comment: Cross-linking with https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/communities/public/questions/202586095-Check-When-Datastore-is-Deleted-iOS-.

Comment: You may want to look at the Lists sample, which deals with this situation: https://github.com/dropbox/lists-ios.

Comment: @smarx I looked at lines 60-70 in DBListViewController which is where they observe the changes to check if the datastore was remotely deleted, but the datastore info isn't returning nil, even though the datastore browser says it doesn't exist.

Comment: @smarx Just checked the datastore browser for the other account, and it seems to have maintained a copy of it.

Comment: Oh, I think I get it. "Deleting" a shared datastore doesn't actually delete it... it just unlinks that user's account from the shared datastore. If you want to revoke other people's access, you should delete the ACLs that give them permission to the shared datastore first.

Comment: @smarx Are you basically just saying to change the roles of the users that can access the shared datastore to none and then deleting it on the owner?

Comment: Yup, that's exactly right.